# What work goes into creating new asymmetric cryptosystems?

Tags: public-key

It's seems to me that it is rather easy to create a symmetric encryption algorithm (though not necessarily a secure one). They're a dime a dozen. The number of asymmetric encryption algorithms probably could probably be counted using the fingers on one hand (all of the RSA-like algorithms, the ECC smorgasbord, McEliece variants, multivariate ones, and lattice-based ones).

A trapdoor function is needed, but are they hard to find? And is the number of possible candidates from which it could be pulled small?

Comment: Is Diffie-Hellman an "RSA-like algorithm"? $\;$

Comment: Much of "the ECC smorgasboard" is really just ECC versions of preexisting systems on finite fields.

Comment: @RickyDemer I'd say no, but I don't consider it to be a cryptosystem.

Comment: @Melab you can build PK encryption from DH (see ElGamal) and don't forget about [Knapsack encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_cryptosystems).